# Partition adjustment on live server

Tags: windows, partition

Windows Server 2008 SP2

I have a server currently running several sites in production. It is partitioned in such a way that the System partition is small with just windows and the necessary program files and all the data is on another partition (the way my hosting company set it up)

Is there a program I can use/purchase that will allow me to resize the system partition to something larger without needing physical access to the machine (ie over RDP)

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to resize a Microsoft Windows server's disk partitions remotely. I have seen this done in the past and it never ends well. An operation this fundamental should always be done with direct access to the server due to the nature of what can happen. I recommend [Acronis Disk Director 10](http://www.acronis.com/promo/ADDS/disk-director.html?source=us_google&ad=adds&c=3311107307&k=acronis%20disk%20director&gclid=COio2LiZ1J8CFQYXagodq2N3aA). It will only take a couple of minutes to resize the partitions but does require physical access since it does this outside of the operating system. Two caveats if you choose this route. If you resize a disk partition with shares on it you will have to recreate the shares. Secondly the volume to be resized must be clean (not have been shut down dirty) or Disk Director will not allow you to resize it until it's clean.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation:

> **[EASEUS Partition Master](http://www.partition-tool.com/)** is an ALL-IN-ONE partition solution and the
>   easiest and most convenient hard disk
>   partition toolkit including Partition
>   Manager, Partition Recovery Wizard and
>   Disk & Partition Copy Wizard for
>   Windows 2000/XP/Vista/Windows 7 and
>   **Server 2000/2003/2008**. It allows users to Resize/Move Partition, Extend
>   System Drive, Copy Disk & Partition,
>   Merge Partition, Split Partition,
>   Partition Recovery, Redistribute Free
>   Space and much more. You can free
>   enjoy EASEUS Partition Master Home
>   Edition

However, before tampering with partition tables you should always take an image of the drive in case something does not go according to plans :)

EASEUS have another excellent (and free) product that will take care of such matters: **[ToDo Backup](http://www.todo-backup.com/)**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually repartition the drive on a running Windows system such as you are proposing. What happens when you run the partitioning software from within Windows is that it will prepare a few things, stop Windows and reboot into it's own software. I've only ever done this using partitioning software on CD or floppy disk but, ss you don't have physical access, perhaps this can be done using a virtual CD image. I really don't know.

What I suggest you do before trying this on your live system is to use one of the virtualisation products that are available to create a virtual machine environment and test it. As for choice of software, there are a number to choose from, both free and commercial.